# It is possible to auto-run an extension for chrome for windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, windows-10-desktop

Our company has installed TV Kiosk around our locations for our employee communication.  We are using HDMI Intel Compute sticks with Windows 10 with a chrome browser to view various URL websites.

We have an extension app Rotisserie [1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rotisserie-url-rotator/iljemanjjfjlglhkmojkmfbpphiaheja/support?hl=en!) which scrolls through various URL websites.  To start the application you have to click on the extension in the bar.  We need to develop a script to launch chrome and start running a chrome extension with out any human interaction.

Our company is posting this a job/gig and is willing to take bids.

Comment: This is not a question. You are asking people to do your job without showing what you already did.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `–kiosk` flag you can use:
https://www.sitepoint.com/google-chrome-kiosk-mode/

If you specify Chromebit as the hardware option this would be easy. It's like a compute stick but it runs Chrome OS.

This support article is for Chromebook but the concept is the same. You can manage all your kiosks without having to be in the building!

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en